# Random Box Generator

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to generate 100 random coloured boxes within the div with the existing by clicking generate button that has top and left position 0-400. Also if I hover over any coloured box it disappears until the last that will give me an alert last box with last box left.

I managed to create a box that generates different colours but im not sure how to generate a 100 let alone hover over and delete the boxes when it is, how would one go about doing that?

My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Generator </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="prototype.js"></script>
  <script src="task4.js"></script>
  <style>
  #container {
    height: 500px;
  }

  p {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 255);
    border: solid 2px black;
    position: absolute;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
</div>
<button id="myButton"
onclick="createBoxes()"> Generate More
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

My JS

```
window.onload = function()
{
  createBoxes();
}
function createBoxes()
{
  var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "purple", "yellow"];

  var newP = document.createElement("p");
  var top = 10 + "px";
  var left = 10 + "px";
  newP.style.top  = top;
  newP.style.left  = left;
  newP.style.backgroundColor = colors[ Math.floor( Math.random() *5 )];

  $("container").appendChild(newP);
}
window.onload = function() {
  createBoxes();

}
```

Comment: appendChild is not a JQuery method. It's a DOM node method.

Comment: Sorry I have to use DOM node methods but im not sure how to generate it

Comment: If you want to use the node object simply replace the jQuery Selector `$("#container")` with the JavaScript selector 
 `document.querySelector("#container")`

Comment: posted an answer, and updated it. @jackson8433 check if this works

Answer (score 2):

Let's get this done step by step.

While creating box element, you should not use `p` tag, `div` is the best choice here.

I have implemented as far as I understood from your question.
Let me know in the comments if I missed something.

I added comments in the code, check if you get it.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  createBoxes();
}

function createBoxes() {
  var left = 0;
  var top = 0;
  var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "purple", "yellow"];
  // create a for loop and run 99 times;
  for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.classList.add('box')
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
    newDiv.style.top = top + 'px';
    newDiv.style.left = left + 'px';
    // now add the event on this one;
    newDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', removeBoxes);
    $("#container").append(newDiv);
    left += 70; // increase left 70px each time in the loop
    if (i % 5 == 0) { // if the we have 5 boxes in one row, reset left to 0px and increase top property by 70px to get another row;
      left = 0;
      top += 70;
    }
  }
}

// function to remove the boxes on hover;
function removeBoxes() {
  $(this).remove();
}

// add the mouseover event listener;
$('div.box').on('mouseover', removeBoxes);
```

```css
#container {
  min-height: 200px;
}

div.box {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 255);
  border: solid 2px black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myButton {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
<button id="myButton" onclick="createBoxes()"> Generate 99 More
    </button>
```